# Rails 3 - Owning and "tracking" the same object type using has_many and has_many as:trackable (polymorphic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism

In my project I need `User` to be able to both "create/own" its own objects and "track" (or "follow") objects created by other users.  Here is my approach:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
  has_many :gadgets
  has_many :nuggets

  has_many :tracks

  has_many :tracked_widgets, :as => :trackable, :trackable_type => "Widget"
  has_many :tracked_gadgets, :as => :trackable, :trackable_type => "Gadget"
  has_many :tracked_nuggets, :as => :trackable, :trackable_type => "Nugget"
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base  # Gadget and Nugget classes are the same
  has_many :tracks, :as => :trackable
end
```

The schema for the `tracks` table:

```
  create_table "tracks", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "tracks", ["trackable_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_tracks_on_trackable_id_and_user_id"
```

With this implementation I get the following error:

```
Unknown key: trackable_type (ArgumentError)
```

Looking at the schema, it's obvious that I don't have `:trackable_type` set up as an index, so the error message makes sense.  However, in the examples I've seen that demonstrate polymorphic relationships, I've never seen the `______able_type` field set up as an index.  This makes me wonder if I'm missing something basic here.  I have these questions:

1. Have I somehow incorrectly set up the `has_many` and `:as => :trackable` relationships?
2. If not, is there any issue using a `string` field as an `index`?
3. If the answer is simply to add the `:trackable_type` field as an index, what is the best way to do this after the fact?  Add a new migration that creates the `:trackable_type` `index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to make the polymorphic association work for this case.  Not sure I understand why, but the `:as` option for `has_many` is not used in some polymorphic cases.  Instead you must use a standard `:through` option and then reestablish the polymorphism with the `:source` and `:source_type` options.

In my example above, the `has_many` statements in the `User` model the needed to be formatted as follows:

```
has_many :tracked_widgets, :through => :tracks, :source => :trackable, :source_type => "Widget"
has_many :tracked_gadgets, :through => :tracks, :source => :trackable, :source_type => "Gadget"
has_many :tracked_nuggets, :through => :tracks, :source => :trackable, :source_type => "Nugget"
```

Hopes this helps anyone trying to address a similar situation.